# Is Polynomial Sequence $(p_n)$ with $p_n(1/l)=(-1)^l, l \in \{1.\dots,n\}$ and $deg(p_n) \leq n$ Bounded

Tags: sequences-and-series, complex-analysis

Is the sequence of entire (i.e. holomorphic on all $\mathbb{C}$) polynomials $p_n$ with $p_n(1/l)=(-1)^l, l \in \{1,\dots,n\}$ and $deg(p_n) \leq n$ bounded on compact sets. That is for every compact set $K \subset \mathbb{C}$ there exists a real number $B_K$ such that $\sup_n(|p_n|) \leq B_K$ on $K$.

I tried using interpolation but it leads to some useless information, Also I noticed that $f(z):=\cos(\pi/z)$ has the property $f(1/l)=(-1)^l$ but it isn't entire so it's likely irrelevant.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By the Lagrange Interpolation formula, for every $c\in C$, we can find a polynomial $p_n$ with $\deg(p_n)\le n$, matching all the specified required values, but also having $p_n(0)=c$. Hence on the unit disk, there is no finite upper bound which works for all such polynomials $p_n$.

Comment: Ah. Damn, I feel ashamed. Of course. Talk about missing the forrest for the trees.