# Is Polynomial Sequence $(p_n)$ with $p_n(1/l)=(-1)^l, l \in \{1.\dots,n+1\}$ and $\deg(p_n) \leq n$ Bounded

Tags: sequences-and-series, complex-analysis

So this is a correction to a [previous question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3280840/is-polynomial-sequence-p-n-with-p-n1-l-1l-l-in-1-dots-n-and)

Notice however that the polynomials are now uniquely determined.

Is the sequence of entire (i.e. holomorphic on all $\mathbb{C}$) polynomials $p_n$ with $p_n(1/l)=(-1)^l, l \in \{1,\dots,n+1\}$ and $\deg(p_n) \leq n$ bounded on compact sets. That is for every compact set $K \subset \mathbb{C}$ there exists a real number $B_K$ such that $\sup_n(|p_n|) \leq B_K$ on $K$.

I tried using interpolation but it leads to some useless information, Also I noticed that $f(z):=\cos(\pi/z)$ has the property $f(1/l)=(-1)^l$ but it isn't entire so it's likely irrelevant.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By symmetry under complex conjugation, $p_n$ has real coefficients, and by the Intermediate Value Theorem, $p_n$ has its $n$ (simple) roots  between the interpolation points, hence
$$p_n(x)=c_n\prod_{l=1}^n (x-\xi_{n,l})$$
with $\frac 1{l+1}<\xi_{n,l}<\frac1l$.
From $$\left|\prod_{l=1}^n \left(\frac12-\xi_{n,l}\right)\right|<\frac1{2^n}$$
and $|p_n(\frac12)|=1$, we conclude $|c_n|>2^n$.
Hence 
$$ |p_n(-1)|\ge 2^n$$
and the desired bound cannot exist on any $K$ containing $-1$.

Comment: Just beautiful! Thanks :)